# How to estimate 95% confidence limit based on maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: r, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I am a research scholar and monitoring phenological events of timber line at a Himalayan region from past 4 years. During data analysis I found a research paper "Estimation and comparison of flowering curve" similar to my work.

In this paper the `R` package `bbmle` was used and five parameters $(\beta_{0},\ldots,\beta_{4})$ which describe: (i) the height; (ii) the peak date; (iii) the range; (iv) the symmetry; and (v) the peakedness of the regression curve were calculated. I also read the appendix table and followed the code to estimate these parameter but as a newbie I failed to do the calculations.

The full appendix table is here:
[image: Appendix table]

I am also posting the `startvals` for the year 2007 as mentioned in the appendix. Look at the values in figure below for year 2007.
[image: Start values for year 2007]

My main problem is how to calculate `startvals` for example data of year 2007 as shown in figure where $(\beta_{0},\ldots,\beta_{4})$ describe:

1. the height
2. the peak date
3. the range
4. the symmetry
5. the peakedness

of the regression curve.